# Automatic upgrade of helm chart files to version 3

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a ton of helm files, with the structure aligned to comply with `Helm2`, i.e. a separate `requirements.yaml` file and no `type:application` in `Chart.yaml`

Is there an option in `helm-2to3` plugin that automagically places the `requirements.yaml` under `Chart.yaml` or do I have to write myself a script to do this?

My charts are checked-in to GH btw (not using a helm repo but operating them via GitOps)

**edit**: After confirmation in answers below that `helm-2to3` does not provide that functionality, I ended up using the draft script below (**warning**: do not use it in production :) ); you can then proceed by a simple `find`/`xargs` oneliner to remove all `requirements.yaml` (or give them an extension of `.bak` to keep around for some time).

the chart should of course be run from the root directory of the project where your `helm` files are kept.

```py
import os
import time


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(".")):
    for file in files:
        if file == "requirements.yaml":
            path = os.path.dirname(os.path.join(root, file))
            print(path)
            os.chdir(path)
            files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
            # print(files)
            if "requirements.yaml" in files and "Chart.yaml" in files:
                requirements_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                print("Doing job in..: ", requirements_path)
                chart_path = path + "/Chart.yaml"
                print(chart_path)
                with open(requirements_path) as req:
                    r = req.read()
                with open(chart_path, 'a') as chr:
                    chr.write(r)
                time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a ton of helm template files, with the structure aligned to comply with Helm2, i.e. a separate requirements.yaml file and no type:application in Chart.yaml

The template files, within the helm chart, should work the same way under Helm 3. It's the Chart.yaml file, in each chart that will need to be edited. Unfortunately the helm-2to3 plugin won't do that for you. It's primarily designed to fix the Kubernetes cluster where you might have previously installed helm charts.

Helm3 is capable of installing older helm charts, so I suggest updating each helm chart one at a time.

To conclude, we're using GitOps too. Happily [ArgoCD](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/) supports both Helm 2 + Helm 3 charts and only uses Helm to generate YAML. This means there is no Helm configuration on the cluster that requires updating. (Miles has a link in his answer, if you're alternatively using [FluxCD](https://fluxcd.io/))

Comment: Thanks for confirming that `helm-2to3` does not do that (yes I was referring to the alignment of `Chart.yaml` specifically). I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I work with the same charts in both Helm 2 and Helm 3 environments.  So long as I make sure to use `helm2 dependency update` to rebuild the `requirements.lock` file, the same charts 99.9% work with both versions of Helm.

Comment: So there is no (pressuring) need to set the `dependencies` within `Chart.yaml` nor to change `apiVersion` from `v1` to `v2` in the same file, right? it can be done at any time later?

Comment: @pkaramol See comment from David

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good plugin that does what you're looking for: https://github.com/helm/helm-2to3

There is also information on migrating a GitOps setup on the Flux CD page (assuming you're using Flux and Helm Operator for your GitOps) https://docs.fluxcd.io/projects/helm-operator/en/stable/helmrelease-guide/release-configuration/#migrating-from-helm-v2-to-v3

Even more information here: https://helm.sh/docs/topics/v2_v3_migration/

Comment: thanks for your reply Miles. I was aware of the `helm-2to3` I just didn't find (or failed to interpret correctly) the actual command that would do the job i wanted (i.e. migrating the actual __template files__; did you happen to spot it?